# This member can only be accessed for a group VBA Word document

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to find ole object in Word document, and It seems to be in `InlineShapes(1).GroupItems`. But can't access group items as it gives me error.

```
Sub findOle()
    Dim shp As GroupShapes
    Dim c As Integer
    Set shp = ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(1).GroupItems
End Sub
```

> this member can only be accessed for a group

I'm able to access `ActiveDocument.Shapes(1).GroupItems.Item(1)` but not with `InlineShapes.`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

If you only have one group of shapes in Word, this would work, when you want to assign it to a shape:

```
Sub FindOle()

    Dim shp         As Shape
    Dim allShapes   As Shape
    Dim c           As Long

    For Each shp In ActiveDocument.Shapes
        Debug.Print shp.Name
        Set allShapes = shp
    Next shp

    Debug.Print allShapes.Name

End Sub
```

After some workaround, here is a good way to use the `GroupShapes` class:

```
Option Explicit

Sub FindOle()

    Dim shp             As Shape
    Dim allShapes       As GroupShapes
    Dim cnt             As Long

    With ActiveDocument.Shapes
        .AddShape(msoShapeIsoscelesTriangle, 10, 10, 100, 100).Name = "shp1"
        .AddShape(msoShapeIsoscelesTriangle, 150, 10, 100, 100).Name = "shp2"
        .AddShape(msoShapeIsoscelesTriangle, 300, 10, 100, 100).Name = "shp3"

        'assign the shapes to a group
        With .Range(Array("shp1", "shp2", "shp3")).Group
            Set allShapes = .GroupItems
        End With

        'format the first and the third shape, prints the name of the shape:
        For cnt = 1 To allShapes.Count
            Debug.Print allShapes.Item(cnt).Name
            If cnt / 2 <> 1 Then
                allShapes.Item(cnt).Fill.PresetTextured msoTextureGreenMarble
            End If
        Next cnt

        'print the name of the shapes in a different way:
        For cnt = 1 To allShapes.Count
            Debug.Print .Range(Array("shp1", "shp2", "shp3"))(cnt).Name
        Next cnt

    End With

End Sub
```

On an empty Word document it creates 3 shapes, assigns them to a group and access them through the `allShapes` variable or through the `.Range(Array())`.

[GroupShapes MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/groupshapes-object-excel)

Comment: Thanks @Vityata, I can easily access ActiveDocument.Shapes object and GroupItems inside it. The main problem is with ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.GroupItem, which throws access violation